# How to modify a public field of a field of a field… As in link.next.next.next(.next*n) n times

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary, hyperlink

I have an array which holds links. Each link has a public field called next which can hold another link, which can hold any more links ect. When I want to delete things I can do

```
array[x].next = array[x].next.next;
```

which would delete the 2nd item. But I want to be able to delete any item, so how can I get it into a form with variables? The equation would be something along these lines: If I wanna delete item n I would do

```
array[x](.next*(n-1)) = array[x](.next*n);
```

Which if n = 4 I want to exand to

```
array[x].next.next.next = array[x].next.next.next.next;
```

Hopefully my question is clear. I need to know how to do it this way as I cannot set a getter or any other code into my link class, and since Im the sole owner of my code I am not going to incorectly set my the field. Java.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers, what you're implementing is a linked list and you'd probably be best served to leverage Java's libraries.

To address the question as you posed it, a function that gives you a reference to the nth hop is probably what you're asking for

```
Link getLink(Link link, int hops){
  Link retVal = link;
  for (int i = 0; i < hops; i++){
    if (link == null){
       //hops is too large. Do something to indicate error
    }
    else{
       retVal = retVal.next;
    }
  }
  return retVal;
}
```

Then you could execute

```
getLink(array[x],2).next = getLink(array[x],4);
```

Or if you wanted to use reflection (not recommended since reflection is relatively expensive), then you could do something like

```
Link myLink = array[x];
Field next = Link.class.getField("next");
//assume proper error handling
for (int i = 0; i < hops; i++){
  myLink = (Link) next.getObject(myLink);
  //assume proper error handling
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you have there is an array of linked lists. I don't know why you're worrying about this fancy syntax expansion stuff when what would work just fine is a method that deletes the nth node, and there are *tons* of implementations floating around the internet.

In fact, you can look at the source for `java.util.LinkedList` and copy that implementation yourself, with simple modifications if you have a singly linked list. Basic formula is:

1. Iterate from the first node, repeatedly finding the next node until the nth node is reached
2. Unlink that node from the chain

Comment: Sounds stupid but I want to do this without adding any cody to the link class. I want to be able to modify it from the array. Deleting an item by just doing
    array[any].next = array[any].next.next
is extremely easy, so surely there is one way to make me be able to have any number of .nexts'??

Comment: So you would like to alter your code during runtime? As in insert an arbitrary number of `.next` accesses?

Comment: I don't _need_ it during run time but essentially yes that is the functionaly I am going for. I wanna be able to pull off a statement exactly the same as array[x].next.next.next = array[x].next.next.next.next; except the .next bit is represented by a variable so there can be an arbitrary number of .next field call things.

Comment: @user142712 I don't believe that's possible without reflection and/or runtime compilation, and those are things that you generally do not want to touch. Unless you wish to hardcode the node you want to access, unfortunately there isn't much you can do, at least from what I know.

Comment: @user142712 Just curious, why not add any code to the `Link` class? You don't even need to put it into the `Link` class, as the fields you need to access are `public` anyways, so once the method is written it really should be as simple as `array[x].nodeAt(i)` to get the ith node.

Comment: Because the way they are being stored isn't relavant to the node, the chaining is in a special case where two nodes share the same array slot. I am planning on having **LOTS** of nodes mainly each in their own array index so the ones that do chain do so using no extra code.

Comment: I guess I can easily write a function which takes the chain as input and outputs the chain minus the one link. Thanks for your help 3580294 :)

Comment: @user142712 So a hash table with chaining? Or something like that? And why not a loop instead of recursive calls?

Comment: Yep, an array with objects indexed by (objects.hash % len)

Comment: @user142712 Oh nice! My particular implementation simply used a loop to traverse the chain, although I never had to calculate how many nodes in I had to go... Just did a hashcode compare and `equals()` to see when to stop. And I believe that's how Java's implementation did it before they changed things up in Java 8

Comment: Thats where I'm stuck. If I do the hash and end up at array[123], then I can check for equals on each one by looping. a[123] = temp; while temp != null - temp.equals(key), else temp = temp.next. 

My problem comes in when I find the one I wanna delete. Say temp.next is one to delete, If I do temp = temp.next.next that wont delete it in the original chain at a[123], it will only change the temp. How can I traverse down the chain then delete without adding more code to the node?

Comment: @user142712 Keep a pointer to the previous node! Or at least that's what I did. Java 8 does something really cryptic, not 100% sure what...

Comment: @user142712 Also, just for future reference; things usually go faster if you ask about the underlying problem either instead of in addition to your attempted solution (called the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). It's great that we got this pretty much figured out, but that way it'll take a bit less time to get to a useful answer for you. Sorry if this seems condescending; just trying to make sure future questions go better

Comment: I agree but I asked the other way first because I didn't really want to loop and I figured people would just tell me to loop if I asked

Comment: @user142712 Why the aversion to loops?

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple loop to step along n times. Here's some code that deletes the nth:

```
Link link = array[x], prev = link;
int n = ?;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    prev = link;
    link = link.next;
}
prev.link = link.next;
```